# Plotting multiple persistent graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show two graphs, which are continually updated by my program. However, my attempted solution is only able to display the second of the two graphs, whilst the first graph appears just as a blank window.

Here is my code:

```
def show1(x, y):
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    fig.canvas.set_window_title("Plot1")
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.pause(0.01)
    plt.show()
    plt.figure(1).clear()

def show2(x, y):
    fig = plt.figure(2)
    fig.canvas.set_window_title("Plot2")
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.pause(0.01)
    plt.show()
    plt.figure(2).clear()

plt.ion()
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
i = 0

while True:
    y1 = [j + i for j in x]
    show1(x, y1)
    y2 = [j + 2 * i for j in x]
    show2(x, y2)
    time.sleep(2)
    i += 1
```

So on each iteration of the loop, the values to be plotted are updated, and the graphs are re-plotted. After plotting each graph, I call `plt.figure(k).clear()` to clear figure `k`, such that the next time I write to the graph, I will write on a blank canvas (rather than having multiple plots continually added to the same graph).

But what happens is that momentarily, I see the first graph display its plot, but then as soon as the second graph is drawn on, the first graph becomes a blank window, and only the second graph actually persists with its displayed plot.

How can I modify my code so that both graphs have a persistent display?

Comment: If you clear the figure `plt.figure(1).clear()` the figure will be blank. No surprise here. There are lots of questions about animating plots in matplotlib around. Why don't you use any of those or at least tell in how far they don't help you?

Comment: I don't think that this is necessarily correct, becase `plt.figure(2).clear()` doesn't clear figure 2. Figure 2 shows its plot, whereas figure 1 does not.

Comment: Figure 2 shows the plot for 2 seconds while Figure 1 shows it for 0.01. Therefore you perceive it as its not being shown at all. I'm a bit tired of explaining how to animate plots once or twice a week; maybe someone else will provide an answer, else just google for working solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig1.canvas.set_window_title("Plot1")

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
fig2.canvas.set_window_title("Plot2")

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
i = 0
# initial plots, so Lines objects exist
line1, = ax1.plot(x, [j + i for j in x])
line2, = ax2.plot(x, [j + 2 * i for j in x])

def show1(y):
    line1.set_ydata(y)  # update data, i.e. update Lines object
    ax1.relim()  # rescale limits of axes
    ax1.autoscale_view()  # rescale limits of axes
    fig1.canvas.draw()  # update figure because Lines object has changed

def show2(y):
    line2.set_ydata(y)
    ax2.relim()
    ax2.autoscale_view()
    fig2.canvas.draw()

while True:
    y1 = [j + i for j in x]
    show1(y1)
    y2 = [j + 2 * i for j in x]
    show2(y2)
    time.sleep(2)
    i += 1
```

Instead of clearing the figure over and over again, just update the plot (i.e. the `Lines` object). This can be useful e.g. when including a Slider (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html), part of the code is from this matplotlib example).